# Can an implicit def be used by a function that does not have an implicit param?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I came across this code block on [this blog](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/StrategicScalaStylePrincipleofLeastPower.html#instantiating-custom-types).  I want to know how `h1("Hello World")` is able to compile since `h1(children: Frag*)`.

```
object TheirCode{
  trait Frag{
    def render: String
  }
  // HTML constructors
  def div(children: Frag*): Frag
  def p(children: Frag*): Frag
  def h1(children: Frag*): Frag
  ...
  implicit def stringFrag(s: String): Frag
}

object MyCode{
  import TheirCode._
  val frag = div(
    h1("Hello World"),
    p("I am a paragraph")
  )
  frag.render // <div><h1>Hello World</h1><p>I am a paragraph</p></div>
}
```

I'm guessing the `implicit def stringFrag` automatically converts `h1(String)` to `h1(Frag)` but I always thought the method param would need the implicit prefix for this to work (i.e. `implicit h1(children: Frag*)`)

Comment: No, you are confusing `implicit` **values** _(or arguments)_ with `implicit` **conversions**. Hope [these](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html) - [materials](https://github.com/BalmungSan/scala-functional-programming-tutorial/blob/master/scala-intro/src/main/scala/co/edu/eafit/dis/progfun/scala/intro/ImplicitsNotes.scala) help. BTW, in this case th autor is using `implicit` **conversions** to model the [**magnet** pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/).

Comment: `div(h1("Hello World"), p("I am a paragraph"))` is actually `div(h1(stringFrag("Hello World")), p(stringFrag("I am a paragraph")))`. There's no need for `h1`, `p` to be implicit. It's enough that `stringFrag` is implicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case we're not talking about implicit parameters at all, but rather [implicit conversions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html). Whenever the compiler finds an `A`, but needs a `B`, it can automatically apply a function of the form `implicit def func(_: A): B` to make the conversion / assignment possible.

Simple example:

```
implicit def string2int(s: String): Int = s.toInt
val i: Int = "2"
```

Note that in order for this to work, you either need to either explicitly import `scala.language.implicitConversions` or use a compiler flag to enable the feature.